# Ajustar botones a tamaño de forma

Tags: vb.net, font-size

lindo día. Quisiera que al momento de maximizar la ventana los botones se ajusten al tamaño de la forma respetando el orden en que los puse, he estado intentando con la propiedad Resize del form pero no logro hacer que los botones que puse se queden en su posicion y **solo** se adapte al maximizar la pantalla.
Alguien tiene idea de como anclar los botones y que sólo se maximice a como lo diseñé? estaría sumamente agradecida.

Comment: Deberiamos ver como armaste tu form, pero no alcanza con la propiedad anchor? igual no sabemos si usas winforms, wpf, uwp o lo que sea que estes usando para diseñar.

Comment: No, no alcanza. Es que son tres botones ubicados de manera horizontal, a la mitad de la forma y si utilizo anchor se distorsionan, yo solo quiero que se mantengan a escala al maximizarlos. Sobre si uso winforms etc, no sabría decirte, en realidad apenas estoy empezando a aprender a programar, ni siquiera sé que es eso

Comment: por como esta tu pregunta, y tu comentario, ni puedo decirte que esta pasando, ni como arreglarlo. Tene en cuenta que no vemos lo que vos ves. Que existen varios modelos de diseño de interfaces, y que vos al generar el proyecto decidiste que tipo de modelo ibas a usar. Por favor, lee [ask], y trata de poner un ejemplo claro de lo que tratas de hacer, lo que hiciste y a lo que queres llegar.

Comment: Ok, estoy usando Winforms y quiero posicionar varios botones a lo largo del form, lo que no sé es como indicar que el button 1 esté siempre en un 10% del width de la forma para que cuando el usuario maximice la ventana cuando esté corriendo el boton permanezca en su lugar y no se vea todo amontonado a la izquierda, @gbianchi :) espero darme a entender.

Comment: Es un problema de anchors.. muestranos como armaste el formulario...